# Set (or initialize) window size when creating window

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to initialize the window size when I creating a new window, what I learned to do is to use a constructor to create a window, then use **resize()** to change the size and main source file. Is there a way to initialize the size while constructing the window? (Initialize list, etc.)
**main.cxx**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "MainWindow.hxx"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        QApplication GUI(argc, argv);
        MainWindow window;
        window.LineEditLogin();
        window.resize(500,300);
        window.setFont(QFont("宋体",16));
        window.show();

        return GUI.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow.cxx**

```
#include<iostream>

#include "MainWindow.hxx"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *Main)
     : QMainWindow(Main)
{

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::LineEditLogin(){
        this->EditUser = new QLineEdit(this);
        EditUser->move(100,100);
        EditUser->setPlaceholderText("请输入账号。。。");

        this->EditPass = new QLineEdit(this);
        EditPass->move(100,150);
        EditPass->setPlaceholderText("请输入密码。。。");
        EditPass->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
}
```

Comment: What should be the advantage when you pass the size of the window in the ctor? And for your subwidgets you should use [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead hard-coded values for the size and position.

Comment: It's because the default size is too small, I want to change it to a bigger default size while constructing, as I can also change the size after it by resize().

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is not unless you subclass the widget. For the MainWindow you can implement the sizeHint() function: [https://myprogrammingnotes.com/size-qt-widgets-determined.html](https://myprogrammingnotes.com/size-qt-widgets-determined.html)